# How to calculate login time of each Jenkins user?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to know how much time it took to login a user into my Jenkins UI. How can I calculate that ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually check it via Google Chrome's Developer tools or using Web server access logs.

Steps :
1. Open Jenkins login page on Google Chrome 
2. Right click and click inspect
3. Go to network view
4. Now login into Jenkins, Network view will show you Http request and http response for Jenkins login. At the bottom on developer tools it will show you time to login.
Example : 70 requests, 300Kb transfered, Finised : 1.60 s , Load 1.60 s

Also you can refer : [Page load time in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059078/page-load-time-in-google-chrome-or-mozilla-firefox)

Also you can get HTTP request and response time in web servers access logs. You can refer : [Understanding Apache's access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234699/understanding-apache-access-log)

Thank you.